# Angular2 : How to have the same guard for multiple components

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In Angular2, is it possible to have the same guard (for exemple CanActivate or CanDeactivate) which can be applied to multiple components ?

Here is a guard for `MyComponent1` :

```
@Injectable()
export class MyGuard implements CanDeactivate<MyComponent1> {

  canDeactivate(component: MyComponent1): Promise<boolean> {
    // my code here
  }
}
```

I want exactly the same guard for `MyComponent2`, `MyComponent3` etc.

How can i implement that ? I need to declare a new guard class by component or can i reuse my class `MyGuard` ?

Answer (score 7):

Just add the same guard to each route where you want it to be applied.

Alternatively you can also create a component-less parent route where you add the guard, and all child routes will be protected by the same guard. 
This only works if the components are all in sibling routes.

Angular DI doesn't support generic type parameters. As a workaround this should do what you want (event though probably more verbose than you want it):

```
routes: [
  { path: 'x', component: MyComponent1, canDeactivate: [new Inject('CanDeactivateMyComponent1') },
  { path: 'y', component: MyComponent2, canDeactivate: [new Inject('CanDeactivateMyComponent2') },

]


@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {provide: 'CanDeactivateMyComponent1', useFactory: () => new CanDeactivate<MyComponent1>()},
    {provide: 'CanDeactivateMyComponent2', useFactory: () => new CanDeactivate<MyComponent2>()},

  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
  ...
})
```

Comment: I think that the doubt of @ElJackiste is about the Type required by the Guard implementation. This is a good answer but maybe not the kind of answer that he's waiting for.

Comment: The fact to have `CanDeactivate<MyComponent1>` don't block the guard class to this component `MyComponent1` ?

Comment: Didn't see the generic parameter. So you want different instances of the guard specialized for the component the guard is applied to. You would need to provide different instances. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you.
With this solution, i don't understand where i define `MyGuard` code ?

Comment: How to write test for the same?

Answer (score 7):

Route:

```
routes: [
    { path: 'x', component: MyComponent1, canDeactivate: ['MyGuard '] },
    { path: 'y', component: MyComponent2, canDeactivate: ['MyGuard '] },
]
```

Guard:

```
@Injectable()    
export class MyGuard implements CanDeactivate<MyComp1 | MyComp2> {    
    constructor() { }    

  canDeactivate(    
    component: PermissionSetsComponent | NodeAccessGroupComponent,    
    ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {    

 // Your code here    
 }    
}
```

Comment: It still is, on Angular9. Don't try to put the Components on `canDeactivate()` different lines - this answer is the correct syntax (all under generic `component`). If you need to fetch Methods form several components to Guard, stick them in `constructor()` - I repeat, NOT under `canDeactivate()`; will not work. Thanks @Candice Moore.

Comment: After all.. you can NOT have any parameters ob the `constructor()` of an Angular's `CanDeactivate` Service implementation... Simply will stop working, the Guard, silentely...

Comment: How to write test for the same? Do we need to create mock for all of them?

Answer (score 3):

Based on [Günter Zöchbauer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41874283/angular2-how-to-have-the-same-guard-for-multiple-components#41874343), I have a solution.

Guard:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyGuard<T> implements CanDeactivate<T> {
  // Maybe some DI here, just inject them into useFactory and deps
  constructor() {}

  canDeactivate(component: T): Promise<boolean> {
    // my code here
  }
}
```

And just provide your guard:

```
routes: [
  { path: 'x', component: MyComponent1, canDeactivate: ['CanDeactivateMyComponent1'] },
  { path: 'y', component: MyComponent2, canDeactivate: ['CanDeactivateMyComponent2'] },

]


@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {provide: 'CanDeactivateMyComponent1', useFactory: () => new MyGuard<MyComponent1>()},
    {provide: 'CanDeactivateMyComponent2', useFactory: () => new MyGuard<MyComponent2>()},

  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just about as verbose but an alternative is to use inheritance to create a new specialized guard.

My generic guard looks something like this:

```
// this goes on the component itself
export interface IUnsavedChangesComponent
{
    hasUnsavedChanges(): boolean;
} 

@Injectable()
export class SaveFormsGuard<C extends IUnsavedChangesComponent> implements CanDeactivate<C>
{
    constructor()
    {
        console.log("SAVEFORMSGUARD");
    }

    canDeactivate(component: C)
    {
        var hasUnsavedChanges = component.hasUnsavedChanges();

        ... dialog box logic ...

        return !hasUnsavedChanges;
    }
}
```

So I create new guards

```
export class SaveFormsGuard_OrderEditor extends SaveFormsGuard<OrderEditorComponent> { }
export class SaveFormsGuard_CustomerEditor extends SaveFormsGuard<CustomerEditorComponent> { }
```

You still have to put them both in the provider list so it didn't turn out to be quite as simplified as I was hoping for - but may be a good pattern to follow if you also need to extend the logic in your guard in other ways.